# I need Glibc install

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, minecraft, glibc

How do I install Glibc 2.28 on linux ? I've looked for different ways and I couldn't.
I need it to start a bedrock minecraft server on a vps.

If you know an easier way to open a server with minecraft bedrock plugins, please tell me, I've been trying for 3 days, I've already created about 8 instances just to start over. Newbie on linux haha!

```
IBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
wine: cannot find './bedrock_server.exe'
node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

Comment: what is the OS you're on? execute `cat /etc/os-release | grep -i version` and paste the output here.

Comment: VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

Answer (score 0):

> How do I install Glibc 2.28 on linux ?

You *don't*.

Instead, select a *distribution* which has that version (or newer) and use it.

You can find which distribution has which version of GLIBC on http://distrowatch.com

Since you tagged your question with `ubuntu-18.04`, it came with GLIBC-2.27. You want *any* newer Ubuntu, e.g. 20.04 (GLIBC-2.31), etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll switch to 20.04 and try again